# Syntax Highlighting for CSS in a Style Tag in a TSX Component

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

In my React app, I like to write CSS style within a style tag of a given TSX component. Is there a way to achieve VS Code syntax highlighting for CSS within this context?

Currently, the entire file reflects TSX syntax highlighting, which means the CSS string fragment is all a single color.

I am not using `styled-components`.

Below is an example of the text I'd like highlighted within the style tag content:

```
export default function HomeStyle() {
  return (
    <style>{`
    .container {
      min-height: 100vh;
      padding: 0 0.5rem;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .main {
      padding: 5rem 0;
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    `}</style>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a tagged template literal named `css` you should get CSS Intellisense & syntax highlighting. eg:

```
const css = String.raw;
 
export default function HomeStyle() {
  return (
    <style>{css`
    .container {
      min-height: 100vh;
      padding: 0 0.5rem;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .main {
      padding: 5rem 0;
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    `}</style>
  );
}
```

If you use a tagged template literal named `html` you should get HTML Intellisense and syntax highlighting. eg:

```
const html = String.raw

const template = html`
  <div class="container"></div>
`
```

In these examples I’m using `String.raw` as a passthrough. Frameworks may provide their own `html` and `css` functions to use for this purpose that add framework specific features.